# Where can you buy real liver (pref. calf's liver) in the western US?

Tags: shopping, liver

I have been looking for 14 years for calf's liver. I know that most processing plants render the organs inedible but the rise of the organic meat movement should make it possible to find. Anyone?

Comment: IMO, the question is too localized and should be closed.

Comment: @Recep I disagree. While the question itself is localized, the answers below are great and could be applied to any situation in which someone is looking for a special section of meat. Often times a question may not perfectly fit what is outlined in the sites FAQ, but can still elicit expert answers that are helpful to not only the OP, but everyone in the community.

Answer (score 8):

Have you asked the meat departments of the stores you shop in?  They may not carry it simply due to lack of demand but could order it for you.

Calve's liver is often sold frozen in small quart size containers due to the fact it's not a high demand item.  Check your freezer section as well as the fresh meat section.

Also look in the yellow pages of your phone book for any meat markets in your area.

Comment: The local Myer (box store/super market) sells it frozen in blister packs. Also check any local butcher/meat market--they are often closer to their sources.

Answer (score 4):

Try a Chinese supermarket with meat produce.